# How to check if a new node version is available on the command line

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface

Good morning, everyone,

all my question is in the title, I would like to know if it is possible to check if a new node version is available on the command line.

For example if today I install version 10.15.3 and in a week a version 10.15.4 is available I would like to know it from the command line when launching a ".bat" file for example.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you have `nvm` installed: `nvm ls-remote`

Comment: Do you have an equivalent on windows?

Comment: Try [this](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows)

Comment: You can find releases [here](https://nodejs.org/dist) and write a node.js CLI or batch file if there is not an off-the-shelf solution.